Lumen "Cannot declare class Event, because the name is already in use in..." after reboot Server
I have a problem that I just can't get any further with.
After restarting our web server, I get an Error 500 from one of our pages. The internal Lumen (Laravel) log spits out the following:
[2024-11-22 11:13:14] local.ERROR: ErrorException: Cannot declare class Event, because the name is already in use in /var/www/vhosts/domainname/subdomain/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Application.php:744
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Laravel\Lumen\Application->Laravel\Lumen\Concerns\{closure}()
#1 /var/www/vhosts/domainname/subdomain/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Application.php(744): class_alias()
#2 /var/www/vhosts/domainname/subdomain/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Application.php(711): Laravel\Lumen\Application->withAliases()
#3 /var/www/vhosts/domainname/subdomain/bootstrap/app.php(29): Laravel\Lumen\Application->withFacades()
#4 /var/www/vhosts/domainname/subdomain/public/index.php(14): require_once('/var/www/vhosts...')
#5 {main} {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Cannot declare class Event, because the name is already in use at /var/www/vhosts/domainname/subdomain/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Application.php:744)
[stacktrace]
#0 [internal function]: Laravel\\Lumen\\Application->Laravel\\Lumen\\Concerns\\{closure}()
#1 /var/www/vhosts/domainname/subdomain/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Application.php(744): class_alias()
#2 /var/www/vhosts/domainname/subdomain/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Application.php(711): Laravel\\Lumen\\Application->withAliases()
#3 /var/www/vhosts/domainname/subdomain/bootstrap/app.php(29): Laravel\\Lumen\\Application->withFacades()
#4 /var/www/vhosts/domainname/subdomain/public/index.php(14): require_once('/var/www/vhosts...')
#5 {main}
"} 

I found an unused file with a class event declaration in App\Http\Events and removed it, unfortunately this did not work. Afterwards I ran a Composer update, which unfortunately also did not bring any success. A search of the files for the keyword ‘Event’ did not reveal any further declarations either.
On the one hand, I'm surprised that this error only occurred after a restart and on the other hand, I'm simply at a loss as to what else it could be... I have never edited the Application.php, it is in its ‘original state’.
Enclosed is my \Bootstrap\app.php. The custom EventServiceProvider is only the base example construct without any "Event" declaration.
<?php

require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

if (!defined('JSON_INVALID_UTF8_SUBSTITUTE')) {
    //PHP < 7.2 Define it as 0 so it does nothing
    define('JSON_INVALID_UTF8_SUBSTITUTE', 0);
}

(new Laravel\Lumen\Bootstrap\LoadEnvironmentVariables(
    dirname(__DIR__)
))->bootstrap();

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Create The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here we will load the environment and create the application instance
| that serves as the central piece of this framework. We'll use this
| application as an "IoC" container and router for this framework.
|
*/

$app = new Laravel\Lumen\Application(
    dirname(__DIR__)
);

 //$app->withFacades();

 $app->withEloquent();

 $app->configure('database');
 $app->configure('session');
 $app->configure('filesystems');
 $app->configure('flysystem');
 $app->configure('mail');
 $app->configure('enums');

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Class Aliases
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This array of class aliases will be registered when this application
| is started. However, feel free to register as many as you wish as
| the aliases are "lazy" loaded so they don't hinder performance.
|
*/

$app->alias('mailer', Illuminate\Mail\Mailer::class);
$app->alias('mailer', Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\Mailer::class);
$app->alias('mailer', Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\MailQueue::class);

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register Container Bindings
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Now we will register a few bindings in the service container. We will
| register the exception handler and the console kernel. You may add
| your own bindings here if you like or you can make another file.
|
*/

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler::class,
    App\Exceptions\Handler::class
);

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class,
    App\Console\Kernel::class
);

$app->singleton(Illuminate\Session\SessionManager::class, function () use ($app) {
    return $app->loadComponent('session', Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class, 'session');
});

$app->singleton('session.store', function () use ($app) {
    return $app->loadComponent('session', Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class, 'session.store');
});

$app->singleton('cookie', function () use ($app) {
    return $app->loadComponent('session', 'Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider', 'cookie');
});
$app->bind('Illuminate\Contracts\Cookie\QueueingFactory', 'cookie');

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register Middleware
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Next, we will register the middleware with the application. These can
| be global middleware that run before and after each request into a
| route or middleware that'll be assigned to some specific routes.
|
*/

 $app->middleware([
    Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
    Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,    
    App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,    
 ]);

 $app->routeMiddleware([
     'auth' => App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
     'monday' => App\Http\Middleware\MondayWebhookLog::class,
     'fullLog' => App\Http\Middleware\Log::class,
     'customerLog' => App\Http\Middleware\CustomerLog::class,
     'cookiecheck' => App\Http\Middleware\CookieCheck::class,
 ]);

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register Service Providers
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here we will register all of the application's service providers which
| are used to bind services into the container. Service providers are
| totally optional, so you are not required to uncomment this line.
|
*/

 $app->register(App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class);
 $app->register(App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class);
 $app->register(Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class);
 $app->register(App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class);
 $app->register(GrahamCampbell\Flysystem\FlysystemServiceProvider::class);
 $app->register(App\Providers\DropboxProvider::class);
 $app->register(Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class);
 $app->register(Flipbox\LumenGenerator\LumenGeneratorServiceProvider::class);

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Load The Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Next we will include the routes file so that they can all be added to
| the application. This will provide all of the URLs the application
| can respond to, as well as the controllers that may handle them.
|
*/

$app->router->group([
    'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers',
], function ($router) {
    require __DIR__.'/../routes/web.php';
});

return $app;


I hope you can maybe help me to solve the error.

maybe look for an loop on the declaration

Okay it seems that I have found the error...
The error is in the call $app->withFacades(); within the app.php.
This causes the classes within the lumen Application.php to be declared twice. If you call withFacades with the parameter false, the classes are not declared again and the whole thing works again.
I then called withFacades again with the parameter true and deleted the standard alias
Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event => Event, and Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL => URL within the Application.php. I had to delete the alias URL as well, as this caused the same problem.
Unfortunately, I don't currently know whether this is a bug in the Lumenframework or whether there is an error somewhere in my own code. At least it is currently working again. :)
